# Unity cloud build with Everyplay plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-cloud-build

I've imported my project to Bitbucket, and trying to set Unity cloud build for it. Everything seems ok, the cloud tries to compile the project for **iOS** target, but with no success.

Here is the part of log:

`37284: [Unity] Ignoring 'Assets/UnityCloud/Scripts/Editor/UnityEditor.CloudBuild.dll' because we're compiling for iOSSupport
37285: [Unity] Plugin 'libeveryplay.so' is used from several locations:
37286: [Unity]  Assets/Plugins/Everyplay/AndroidDynamicLibraries/armeabi-v7a/libeveryplay.so would be copied to /libeveryplay.so
37287: [Unity]  Assets/Plugins/Everyplay/AndroidDynamicLibraries/x86/libeveryplay.so would be copied to /libeveryplay.so
37288: [Unity] Please fix plugin settings and try again.
37289: [Unity] UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
37290: [Unity] UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])`

Strings 37285 and 37288 are red and the project can't be compiled. Files **libeveryplay.so** are marked for android only in the project, but, as I understand, the cloud tries to include tham both, and compile failed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it turned out to be caused by a .meta file not being synced correctly with the version in our repository. The local file looked fine, but the file in the repository (the one UCB downloads) did not have the correct plugin importer settings, resulting in the same error you got.

1. Make sure Import Settings are set to Android only for both files
2. Push to repository (make sure files are modified)
3. Build

[image]
[image]